# How do I delete all non-confirmed users in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extension

I had an issue that bots/spammers have created hundreds of users on our mediawiki page.

They are not harmful, since a user needs to be confirmed before it can edit, and neither have been.

I have now installed a captcha to stop that - http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ConfirmEdit

How can I clean this huge list of users? *it spans over more than a day

[image]

Comment: Write a `DELETE` query that will delete every user with the creation date between `00:00:01` and `23:59:59` on `May 28 2013`.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure that this is limited to that one day, the screenshot probably doesn't list all the spammer users. Also, what if a legitimate user was created on that day?

Comment: @svick - All important information to have in the question.  A egitimate user would just create their account again.

Comment: It sounds like your question is "How do I delete all non-confirmed users?"

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the following extension called UserMerge:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserMerge

With UserMerge can merge the offending accounts into one and then delete the remaining account. I don't know if UserMerge will allow you to merge en mass; if not it may not be an ideal solution.

You can also use Nuke to mass delete pages created by an offending account:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Nuke

Also a similar post on StackOverflow gives instructions on how to use SQL to neutralize an account:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706451/mediawiki-mass-user-delete-merge-block

Best of luck! I have had the same problem on my Mediawiki install.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a solution for the mass user delete so this is what I did in the end:

Deleted all pages added by spammers using:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Nuke

then log into mysql:

```
 mysql -h localhost -u user -p passwrd db_name
```

and there:

```
 DELETE FROM db_name WHERE NOT user_name='Admin'
```

It may leave some inconsitencies but so far it seems to work fine.